# Update pattern table and use it

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

I've a question regarding Table API in flink. I want to use it to create real time alert system. I want my pattern stream to update at times when new patterns are being made, for this can I use upsertStream command on pattern table? if so can anybody help me by attaching a snippet or anything helpful

Use Case is :-
whenever a new pattern appears it gets updated in kafka stream for pattern of a particular topic.Then whenever pattern matching takes place the whole pattern table is used as continuous query. Hope I explained the question pretty well, ask for clarfications if needed. 
Kindly help, Thank You

> The question has been solved. Ping me if you have any query related to it

Comment: I've deleted my answer because after looking at your code I can't understand what you are trying to do. It doesn't seem to involve pattern matching.

Comment: What I'm trying to do @DavidAnderson is if the ID matches the ID of event stream, then it'll check the temperature(permissible temperature) if event's temp is above the permissible then it'll create an alert, pretty much CEP . https://github.com/ASKRAJPUT5/flink-Table/tree/master/src/main/scala